# Black screen with blinking cursor unresponsive keyboard

Tags: command-line, mbr

Removed my mbr because it was currupt​. I had intended to replace with an uncorrupted copy  but after l removed it I just got a blinking cursor without​ ability access command line. Keyboard will respond with beeps if I hold key down long enough. I have had issues with boot process for a long time so lt has finally caught up with me. Used DVD copy of os but get 1. 2. Select CD-ROM boot type: I think if boot process is fixed DVD will boot.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: a little vague.  after removing mbr (boot sector) you should have got command prompt (etc) allowing you to rewrite it; but I assume you rebooted causing blinking cursor, and keyboard beeps are being created by POST routine in machines hardware.

I assume you've got an old non-UEFI machine; or a more modern set in legacy mode.  first thought is to check BIOS on machine to ensure it'll boot CD/DVD/usb etc; as security these days often tells it to boot HDD/sdd only to avoid malware issues which will stop what you're trying to do from `infecting` system.  keys for this dictated by brand hardware

Comment: I didn't get command prompt for (etc) before I ran reboot. I enabled UEFI in my BIOS with boot order as CD/DVD when using a DVD and USB when using a USB but I get the same malfunction.

Comment: Is there a way to get a command line?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use fixmbr tools, to rewrite a standard MBR? The problem is that if the original MBR was not a standard one it might ruin all disk data...

The first sector "zero" have the MBR and also the disk partition table, which defines where the filesystem starts and ends, if that is lost are in need of tool that searches sector by sector for the 55AA signature at the 512 byte sector...

Downloading Ubuntu ISO and installing it to an USB pen will give you a bootable disk, just choose in the BIOS setup to boot from the PEN first.

Comment: Trying to boot from USB but it appears machine is having a difficult time reading it. Black screen with blinking cursor takes longer to appear but it does. BIOS is set to give USB priority.

Comment: Switched out hard drive and it boots without issue. Don't want to mark as solved until data on old hard drive is successfully transferred.